# Changing text displayed in an excel hyper link to a different cell for a whole row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with tons of hyper links. I want the text displayed to be what is in another cell. For example, my hyperlinks are in column D, and the text I want displayed is the corresponding cell in column C. Is there a macro or something I can make and run to change the text displayed to the matching cell in column C? There is WAY to many for me to do it manually.

Comment: ???  ***ROW*** C or ***COLUMN*** C ???

Comment: So, my links are in Row D, and the text I want displayed is in Row C.

Comment: Crap. I meant column. I'm sorry. Flu has my brain not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub TheMissingLink()
    Dim h As Hyperlink, r As Range

    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If Not Intersect(h.Range, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
            h.TextToDisplay = h.Range.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next h

End Sub
```

This assumes that the hyperlinks are the ***Inserted*** kind rather than the ***formula*** kind.

Comment: That worked. For some reason, the first 7 cells it didn't work, but it did for the other 29K+ cells. I just did those first 7 manually. Thank you